# Can I configure rspec + capybara to not blow away by DB each time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I know that generally you want your test suite to run against a freshly configured set of data each time tests are run. However, I have a site with a fairly set of static data. Is it possible to have my tests run against my local db that has been populated from my production database? I have this DB configured in my database.yml file, however the db gets blown away each time a I run tests, and I'd like it to remain static.

Is this possible with rspec?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not need database_cleaner gem. Turns out I was running `rake spec` which was truncating my DB each time. Instead if I run `rspec spec` the DB is *NOT* truncated.

Answer (score 2):

With the database_cleaner gem, you can limit which tables get truncated:

https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner#how-to-use

Comment: Thanks Andy. This looks promising. I tried adding `DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation` to my spec helper, and my spec and my database is still truncated. Intuitively I want to set truncation to false, but don't see a way to do that. Any ideas?

Comment: I haven't tried, but the README says there's an option `DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation, {:except => %w[widgets]}` so you exclude the tables that need to be preserved.

Comment: Yes, tried that but no worky. I'll keep digging and post my solution here when I find it.